# regex how to find and replace at multiple instance along multi line search

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following text:

```
vyāsa-prasādāc chrutavānZKL
etad guhyam ahaṁ paramZKL
yogaṁ yogeśvarāt kṛṣṇātZKL
sākṣāt kathayataḥ svayamPXY

rājan saṁsmṛtya saṁsmṛtyaZKL
saṁvādam imam adbhutamZKL
keśavārjunayoḥ puṇyaṁZKL
hṛṣyāmi ca muhur muhuḥPXY

tac ca saṁsmṛtya saṁsmṛtyaZKL
rūpam aty-adbhutaṁ hareḥZKL
vismayo me mahān rājanZKL
hṛṣyāmi ca punaḥ punaḥPXY

yatra yogeśvaraḥ kṛṣṇoZKL
yatra pārtho dhanur-dharaḥZKL
tatra śrīr vijayo bhūtirZKL
dhruvā nītir matir mamaPXY
```

Now i want:

```
vyāsa-prasādāc chrutavānZKL
etad guhyam ahaṁ paramZKL
yogaṁ yogeśvarāt kṛṣṇāt sākṣāt kathayataḥ svayamPXY

rājan saṁsmṛtya saṁsmṛtyaZKL
saṁvādam imam adbhutamZKL
keśavārjunayoḥ puṇyaṁ hṛṣyāmi ca muhur muhuḥPXY

tac ca saṁsmṛtya saṁsmṛtyaZKL
rūpam aty-adbhutaṁ hareḥZKL
vismayo me mahān rājan hṛṣyāmi ca punaḥ punaḥPXY

yatra yogeśvaraḥ kṛṣṇoZKL
yatra pārtho dhanur-dharaḥZKL
tatra śrīr vijayo bhūtir dhruvā nītir matir mamaPXY
```

I want to merge the last two lines in each stanza.

I am trying in sublime text:

```
find: (?s)ZKL\n((?!.*ZKL).*PXY)
replace:  \1

(?s)  for multi line search
ZKL\n is ZKL and new line
((?!.*ZKL)  to search from ZKL which is before PXY otherwse there are many ZKL
.*PXY everything till PXY
```

the above will only replace the last instance. How to see that all four instances in four stanzas are replaced.

i have lot off such stanzas

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stanza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex seems to work PCRE. I am not sure about sublimetext3, can you try this regex?

```
ZKL\n(?=.*\n\n)
```

and replace it with just a single space.

Note: I have inserted two new lines after the last paragraph, so that the regex works for last paragraph as well.

[Check here](https://regex101.com/r/z6zsCC/1)

**Edit:**
In case you want to further combine PXY line with two lines above it, you can use `ZKL\n` and replace it with space.

But in case you want to combine all four lines into one whist removing ZKL and PXY at the end, you can use this regex,

```
(ZKL|PXY(\n))\n
```

and remove it with a `\2\2`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z6zsCC/2/)

Comment: @Santhosh: I've updated my answer for the requirement you mentioned in a comment in another answer. Hope that helps. Let me know if you face any issue further or have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ZKL\n(?=.*PXY\n\n)
```

It matches ZKL followed by a new line, then checks if there are a bunch of non-new-line characters followed by PXY followed by 2 new lines after that.

You can replace it with a space.

Note that for this to work for the last stanza, you need to have at least two new lines at the end of the file.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWlFGR/1)

Comment: After joining the last two lines, Now i also want to join the line above PXY with the two lines above PXY

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Can you show what you expect to get for the first stanza?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the job:

```
(.+ZKL\n.+ZKL\n.+ZKL)\n(.+PXY)
```

The regex matches any number of `any char` up to `'ZKL\n'`. This is repeated three times and is stored in `Group 1`.

Then it matches any number of any char up to `'PXY'` This is stored in `Group 2`.

Now you replace with:

`$1$2`    or in some languages: `\1\2`

That will join the last two lines.

You should set the `global` flag.